# How to qsort array of integer pointers?

Tags: c, qsort

I have the following function that needs to return an array of pointers to a sorted list

```
int **list_elements_sorted(int *array, int n)
{
  if (n <= 0)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  int **sorted_list = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
  assert((sorted_list != NULL) && "Error! Memory allocation failed!");

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    sorted_list[i] = &array[i];
  }

  qsort(sorted_list, n, sizeof(int *), comp_list_asc);

  return sorted_list;
}
```

And the comparator function

```
int comp_list_asc(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  int *A = *(int **)a;
  int *B = *(int **)b;

  return (A - B);
}
```

When I input an array  E.G: `3 2 5` I'm getting the same output `3 2 5`, what I'm doing wrong ?

```
void test_sorted_list_valid_3(void **state)
{
  int **output;

  int n = 3;
  int int_list[] = {3, 2, 5};
  int *int_list_sorted[] = {&int_list[1],
                            &int_list[0],
                            &int_list[2]};

  output = list_elements_sorted(int_list, n);

  assert_memory_equal(int_list_sorted, output, n);
  free(output);
}
```

Comment: `3 2 5` is not an array of pointers, it is an array of integers. And your `sorted_list` should be such

Comment: I suspect (A-B) will always give you a positive result due to pointers being unsigned (aka the void type). But I'am not sure...

Comment: @EugeneSh. `sorted_list` is an array of pointers pointing to the `array` integers, array is my input

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: This does not make sense. You are expecting *integers* `3 2 5` to come out sorted (aren't you?), not their addresses.

Comment: I edited to show one case of testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're subtracting pointers, instead of integers. The below change should work for you.

```
int comp_list_asc(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  int *A = *(int **)a;
  int *B = *(int **)b;

  return (*A - *B); // here's the change
}
```

As pointed out by @tstanisl, subtracting integers is prone to overflow/underflow errors. These can be addressed by changing the return statement like below.

```
return *A == *B ? 0 : *A < *B ? -1 : 1;
```

Comment: it's sensitive to integer overflows, i.e. `*A == INT_MAX` and `*B == INT_MIN`

Comment: Is this really all it took to fix the problem? I don't get it ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to dereference `A` and `B` before subtracting in `comp_list_asc`.

You also sort the wrong thing, `int_list` (which is not an array of `int*`), instead of `int_list_sorted`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int comp_list_asc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    int *A = *(int **)a;
    int *B = *(int **)b;

    return *A - *B;      // dereference
}

int main() {
    int int_list[] = {3, 2, 5};

    int *int_list_sorted[] = {&int_list[0],
                              &int_list[1],
                              &int_list[2]};

    int n = sizeof int_list_sorted / sizeof *int_list_sorted;

    // Sort the correct thing:

    qsort(int_list_sorted, n, sizeof(int *), comp_list_asc);

    // Print result to compare input and output:

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d %d\n", int_list[i], *int_list_sorted[i]);
    }
}
```